# Are our current Mods going to still be mods?

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

After the election and we receive 3 new mods, what is going to happen to the three mods we have now?

Are they going to get the boot? Are they going to be the [Elders](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elder_%28administrative_title%29), wise beings that the rulers of the land go to for advice? [The Givers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Giver), a person who gives all knowledge  of their title to a new Receiver and then goes off into the abyss?

Comment: oooo. I like elder. Can we swap the diamonds for wands?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Mods Pro Tempore will no longer be moderators (here) unless they run and win.  So far, none have nominated themselves so it looks unlikely (though there is still time should one or more wish to do so).

Comment: Correct. As I'm sure some have noticed, I'm around less (more work, promotion, so on) so it wouldn't be fair for me to toss my hat in.